# signInWithEmailAndPassword Firebase, Android Studio, kotlin not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to use Firebase to store my emails and passwords. On my Sign-Up page, maybe 5% of the time, the code will run smoothly with no problems. However, when it does run, I have to wait a decent amount of time before it will register the new user within Firebase (about 3-5 minutes). All of my Toast messages go through except for the "Sign up success" and "it.exception.toString()" because it rarely completes the process. I assume the problem lies within the "firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword..." block, but I am not able to fix the problem.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blueCFSLogo"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blue_cfs_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signUpTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lobster_regular"
            android:letterSpacing=".05"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blueCFSLogo"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.514" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/email"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtPasswordPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtConfirmPasswordTil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/signUpBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" >

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alreadyHaveAccount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                android:letterSpacing=".05"
                android:text="Already have an account?"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bolditalic"
                android:letterSpacing=".05"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

.kt file:

````
package com.countdownfantasysports.app

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
import com.countdownfantasysports.app.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_sign_up.*

class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.login.setOnClickListener {
            val loginIntent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(loginIntent)
        }

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.signUpBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val email = binding.emailEditText.text.toString()
            val password = binding.passwordEt.text.toString()
            val confirmPassword = binding.confirmPasswordEt.text.toString()

            if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty() && confirmPassword.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (password == confirmPassword){
                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener{
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {

                            // If successful, start MainActivity
                            val mainIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(mainIntent)

                            // If successful, display message for user
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Sign up success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                            // If successful, log success
                            Log.d("Isaac", "createUserWithEmail:success")

                        } else {

                            // If failure, display message for user
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                it.exception.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                            // If failure, log failure
                            Log.w("Isaac", "createUserWithEmail:failure")
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    // If passwords do not match, display message to user
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Password does not match",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {

                // If empty fields, display message for user
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Empty fields are not allowed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        // Start LoginActivity
        binding.login.setOnClickListener {
            val loginIntent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(loginIntent)
        }
    }
}```


I have tried mulitple builds, but this seems to be the only on that completes 5% of the time. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!
````

Comment: I found the issue! I needed to update my android studio...rookie mistake! However, upon competion of Login, the UI does not direct to my 'MainActivity', instead it cycles back to the 'LoginActivity'.

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).